# How do I recall an sObject from an approval process using apex?

Tags: apex, approval-process

While the apex developer documentation provides sample code on submitting an sObject to an approval provess with apex there is no documentation on how to recall an item from the approval process.

Is this possible? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible by setting the *action* on a *ProcessWorkItemRequest* to "Removed". Depending on the configuration of your approval process this option may only be available to system administrators. If the approval process is set to "Allow submitters to recall approval requests" then the submitter of the record can also recall it.

Sample apex:

```
Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest PWR = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
PWR.setComments(approverComment);
PWR.setAction('Removed');
PWR.setWorkitemId(record.Id);
Approval.ProcessResult result =  Approval.process(PWR);
```

Comment: does the approval.processResult count as a DML?

Comment: Hey Chris, this just got flagged as apparently it doesn't workin the latest version of the API. Got any insight on that or is it likely to be something else?

Comment: Nothing at the moment. I'll see if I can replicate it not working.