# Approval Process Question

Tags: approval-process

Situation:
We have an Approval Process on an Object. We start the Approval Process with two ProcessInstances(for two user) at the same time.

One user(User A) approves and the status of the other ProcessInstance is still pending.

If now User A wants to change from approve to reject, this is not easily possible because he has to wait for User B and his approval. 
Is it correct that the only way to do this is to remove the processInstance of User B (since both processInstances are in the same step)?

Comment: Can you clarify just a bit more what you are trying to achieve.  Most of your scenario makes sense, I'm just not positive what it is you are asking.

Comment: We have the same problem with this question. 
[Any way to recall arbitrary approval requests from Trigger?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50634/any-way-to-recall-arbitrary-approval-requests-from-trigger?rq=1)